# How can I add programmatically a more complex column in an gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have the following columg:

```htmll
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="imbDelete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/icon_Delete.png"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete attachment?');" CommandName="Delete"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Path" HeaderText="Path" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" />
```

That I must insert programmatically in my code using C#. Can someone please help? I don't know how to insert ImageButton in a TemplateField or even insert all this data at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than dynamically inserting it, I'd recommend setting `Visible="False"` on it, and in code set it to true when you want to show it.  It will be much easier to manage then; for instance, in RowDataBound event handler, you can do:

```
GridView_RowDataBound(..)
{
    var deleteButton = e.Row[0].FindControl("imbDelete");
    deleteButton.Visible = (some condition);
}
```

Comment: Nope, this don't satisfy my needs. I need to input more Complex columns dynamically and programmatically.

Comment: Maybe then providing more details why would be helpful... you can show/hide any number of simple or complex controls, and works in 99% of the situations...

Comment: Sorry if I sounded rude, but I'm fairly new at this.

Anyway, I kinda solved that like this.

Answer (score 0):

i've ever do that with an asp button and using a CssClass for the picture.

```
 <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="imbDelete" runat="server" CssClass="buttonDelete"
            OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete attachment?');" CommandName="Delete"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Path" HeaderText="Path" ReadOnly="True" Visible="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="True" />
```

then in your CssClass :

```
.buttonDelete
{
border:none;
background:url(../../images/buttonDelete.png) no-repeat;
}
```

if you want you can change the picture on hover like that :

```
.buttonDelete:hover
{
background:url(../../images/buttonDelete-hover.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to hide columns.

Comment: You don't hide columns with my code, the CSS is only to change the appearence of the button on mouse hover !